# Custom loop pagination issue ( pagination not showing up )

Tags: pagination

I have a pagination issue in my custom loop, here is the loop.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args=array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'paged'=>$paged,
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$i = 0;
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
if($i % 7 == 0) { ?> 
<?php
}
?>
    !!!LOOP CONTENT!!!

    <?php $i++; 
    if($i != 0 && $i % 7 == 0) { ?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php
    } ?>
    <?php  
    endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
    <?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
```

And my question is: Why pagination link not even showing up in this case?

Comment: What is `wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav()`? It doesn’t even take the custom query or any parts of it as an argument, so I don’t know how it’s even supposed to work.

Comment: My bad, the rest of it is in the function.php file. But normally I tried to use this: `<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>`  but it doesnt work anyway

Comment: for using `next_posts_link()` with a custom query, read https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query

Comment: Ok, it's done with `net_posts_link()` but how can I change this to wp_pagenavi with numerical pagination?

Answer (score 0):

**Step:1** Put step 1 code in **function.php**

```
// numbered pagination
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
?>
```

**Step:2**

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 6,
   'paged' => $paged
);
```

**Step: 3** After while loop completed before wp_reset_query();

```
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($my_query->max_num_pages);
} ?>
```

NOTE: Reference link : after while change [wp_reset_query();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) TO [wp_reset_postdata();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)

Comment: Thank's! It's showing up now but pages links have a class=inactive and I can't click on them, what's wrong?

Comment: Use this CSS for pagination : Reference link for that : https://www.evan-herman.com/how-to-add-numeric-wordpress-pagination/#.WwgOrTSFPcs